# If $ \frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, then is it true that $0 \leq \left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\leq \frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, solution-verification, proof-writing

If $ \frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then are the following lines true?

$$ -1 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) \leq -\frac{1}{4} \quad \quad (1)$$
$$ \Rightarrow -2 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) - 1 \leq -\frac{5}{4} \quad \quad (2) $$
$$\Rightarrow  -2 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) - 1 < \frac{3}{4} \quad \quad (3)$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 \leq \left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right| <\frac{3}{4} \quad \quad (4)$$

I am most concerned with inequalities (3) and (4). Since $\frac{-5}{4} < \frac{3}{4}$, I obtained (3). Furthermore, $|-(x^2 + y^2) -1| \geq 0$ since it is an absolute value. Hence, the (4).

Are these justifications valid?

Comment: $|-(x^2+y^2)-1| = x^2+y^2+1$ is always larger than $3/4$.

Comment: You can set $(x, y) = (1, 0)$ and check where your calculation goes wrong.

Comment: You were right to have doubts about your "Hence, the (4)".

Comment: You missed $-(x^2+y^2)-1 < 0$. Also, (3) is too loose... Anyway, because of (3), (4) has to be $0 \leq |-(x^2+y^2)-1| < 2$. (If you delete (3), (4) becomes $\dfrac 5 4 \leq |-(x^2+y^2)-1| \leq 2$.)

Comment: The solvers have made the necessary clarifications for the OP. Your problem will be correct for $0 \leq \left|(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\leq \dfrac{3}{4}$. On the other hand, could you have made a typo while writing your question?

Answer (score 1):

Inequality (1) is correct; you have reflected your given inequality across the origin.

Inequality (2) is correct; you have shifted (1) in the negative direction.

When working with inequalities, it is unusual to throw away information. This is what you have done by writing (3), although it is correct.

(2) is preferable to (3) for you, in particular, because it shows that $-(x^2+y^2)-1$ is a negative number. I would move from (2) to (3b) by another reflection across the origin:

$$ \frac{5}{4}  \leq -(-(x^2 + y^2) - 1) \leq 2, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (3b)$$

$$ \frac{5}{4}  \leq (x^2 + y^2) + 1 \leq 2. \quad\quad  \quad \,\,\,\quad \quad \quad \quad (4b)$$

Your error in moving from the true (3) to the wrong (4) is of this form:

$$ a < b \quad \implies \quad |a| < b.$$

Of course the part of (4) claiming that $|a| \geq 0$ for any $a$ is correct.

Comment: Jordan G, is what I wrote here clear to you? Also user has written an answer for your question, is that answer clear to you?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|=x^2+y^2+1>0$$

and

$$\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \iff \frac{5}{4} \leq x^2 + y^2 +1\leq 2$$

but

$$0 \leq \left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\leq \frac{3}{4} \iff 0 \leq x^2+y^2+1\leq \frac{3}{4}<\frac 5 4$$

Note that in your derivation from $(3)$ to $(4)$ we have

$$-2 \leq -(x^2 + y^2) - 1 < \frac{3}{4} \implies 0 \leq \left|-(x^2+y^2)-1\right|\leq 2$$